# Regular expression to extract text in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has a function name with a parameter inside

```
Load_Data( 140067676 )
```

I need to get those numbers from the string. It should match `Load_Data( )` too because there are other parentheses in the string.

What I came up with is this:

```
/(Load_Data)\( ([^)]+) \)/
```

But it looks like it would come up with two matches. I'm bad with regex, any help would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean, "two matches"? Your regex will match that string you've got, with two capturing groups. The first capturing group will contain "Load_Data", the second will be "140067676 ". Did you want only one capturing group, containing the parameter?

Comment: @ChrisKitching What I mean is that the string has many more strings like `Load_Something( 123 )` but I only need the numbers inside the `Load_Data` one.

Comment: This regex should also have that property, if you use it right. Perhaps add the code that uses this regex to your question? (And maybe an example of a complete string, too?)

Comment: @ChrisKitching Oh.. I didn't expect it to work. Now that you mentioned it I tested it out and I can get the right value extracted. Thanks.

Comment: You posted on StackOverflow before checking if your program actually worked? :P